# Google API unique identifier for country

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

**Background (skippable)**

I'm currently working on a project to allow our webapplication to show the [Corruption Perceptions Index](http://www.transparency.org/cpi2015) (CPI) score for the countries of the addresses that are and will be stored in our platform.

This sounds easy but these CPI scores get updated annually and we want this score to be up-to-date for all the countries stored in our platform. Of-course we don't want to do this by annually scanning through all the addresses stored in the platform and making the required changes, this is to fault sensitive (countries can be stored in the platform in different languages sot it might skip some and show old scores for countries in different languages). And not all countries have a CPI score.

One solution I have come up with is to separate the CPI score from the addresses table and having a ID which can be referenced from the original Addresses table. This way you only have to update the CPI score once for every country instead of for all translation variations. But another problem remains how to lay the link between the country and CPI. Because if I store an address with the country 'Deutschland' it won't be able to detect that this is a translation of 'Germany' in german without a translator module. Since we are using the google maps API I figured it would be great if we could use some kind of country ID from the google API (like the place ID in [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder) article) and by storing this ID together with the countryname and by using this ID as a reference between CPI and original Addresses table.

**Core question**

Does google have an unique identifier for countries only that is accessible through the API (similar to the [place ID](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder))?

Comment: They use [ISO 3166-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1)

Answer (score 1):

The unique identifier for any feature in Google Maps Geocoding API is place ID. Each country also has a place ID.

How can you find it? Please take into account that Geocoding API has a [components filtering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?hl=en#ComponentFiltering) that allows to set country filter.

The country filter accepts two letter ISO 3166-1 country code.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2

So, if you need a place ID for Germany just execute the following request:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country%3ADE&key=YOUR_API_KEY

This returns the place ID ChIJa76xwh5ymkcRW-WRjmtd6HU.

The same result you can obtain using the Geocoder tool:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D%26options%3Dtrue%26in_country%3DDE